# C++ Friendship and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, access-control

I know that friendship is not inherited. I was asking myself: why? Why the C++ designers decided to not let friendship be inherited? Do you find that friendship inheritance would be a useful thing to have? My own answer is yes: in the same way that B is a friend of A, i would like to make a whole family of classes be friend of A (B and its derivatives). Maybe, one should be able to say: let **only** B be friend of A or let B **and** its derived classes be friend of A.

Ps.
I don't know why many of you thought that i was asking for *automatic* extension of friendship. I was interested more in the possibility for the programmer to extend friendship to a whole family using some mechanism (not automatically).

Comment: You haven’t shown a compelling use-case. Personally, I don’t see the usefulness. You don’t need to inherit friendship in most cases, since you can just use normal inheritance: function `foo(A&)` which is a friend of `A` does of course also work with an argument of type `B`.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.4

Comment: The whole purpose of `Friend`ship is to indicate that two entities having strong coupling, allowing Friendship to be Inherited and propagate it along hierarchies would break this very basis for the existence of Friends and also break the very OOP principles .

Comment: I think you want to wait for modules (such as `internal` protection level in C# or `default` protection level in Java). Such a thing could allow a group of classes (those in the same module) access default/internal attributes.

Comment: So I write a DB class and DB worker class were the worker is a friend of the DB (becuase I implement them together I know I can trust th worker not to behave baddly). Now you com along and write EvelWorker that inherit from the DB worker. My DB definitely does not like EvelWorker as you have no idea how the DB works internally.

Answer (score 4):

A `friend` declaration creates a strong relationship between the Friendly and the Trusting:

- it ties down the Friendly to the representation of the Trusting since it's got full access to its internals
- it means that the Friendly swears to uphold the class invariants of the Trusting

Therefore it seems good practice to make sure to clearly identify the exact scope, something that inheritance would not achieve: there would be a leak.

The truth is though, that inheritance should not even be *necessary*. There are actually two alternatives, depending on what friendship is trying to achieve. They cover any scenario I ever come across.

***Friendly*** as a Proxy

In your example, derivates of `Friendly` can simply reach into `Trusting` through `Friendly`, thus letting you control the operations that occur on `Trusting` in a limited set of places.

```
class Trusting { friend class Friendly; };

class Friendly { protected: void modifyTrusting(); };
```

The implementation of `modifyTrusting` might imply virtual calls (hooks) to customize the behavior, but regardless of those hooks it is up to `Friendly` to ensure that the class invariants are not broken.

**Not so *Trusting***

In this case, `Trusting` opens up only part of its interface, through a locked method, and grants the key to `Friendly`. `Friendly` might alternatively grant the key to the classes in which it trusts, but it does not really matter... In any case `Trusting` ensures itself that its invariants are not broken, and the key is just a mechanism to reduce the exposure of the method.

```
class Key { friend class Friendly; Key() {} ~Key() {} };

class Trusting { public: void doSomething(Key const&); };

class Friendly { protected: Key const& key() const; };
```

I must admit that I am really partial to this latter method and use it regularly, because it limits the exposure of `Friendly` to the implementation details of `Trusting`. It also clearly documents which parts of `Trusting` our dear `Friendly` access.

Answer (score 2):

I saw an amusing bumper sticker yesterday: "My mother-in-law is a travel agent ... *for guilt trips*". Friendship is inherited to some extent in human relationships. While this does lead to interesting jokes about an SOs friends and family, it is important to remember that misery and suffering are the basis for many jokes.

Friendship is not inherited in C++ because the developers foresaw the amount of misery and suffering this would cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible idea.

Friendship is not inherited because friendship causes a tight coupling between friends. If all the derived class were also automatically friends then this would cause a tight binding between the original object and all inherited classes.

Tight coupling is fine for classes that are created and maintained together. But for classes that are created by other users tight coupling would cause a maintenance nightmare and prevent you from ever changing the original object (because all your tightly coupled friends depend on your implementation).